# Visio to PDF API for Linux and Windows

Tags: java, pdf, visio

I'm evaluating transformers to find visio to pdf transformer. I found there is none. Is there any external third party api that can convert visio to pdf(Both Linux and Windows). I found easyPDF api, but it only support windows platform.

Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://vdxtosvg.sourceforge.net/) might help, but it requires prior conversion from Visio binary format to Visio XML format. So you could require users to save in that format, or look to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Certainly a third party API would be possible - it would probably have to be on Windows itself, however, as [there's probably no Visio reader for *nix](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/visio-viewer-871414/). But such an API could be made available over standard XML services.